# Code optimalisation with concatenation

Tags: php, html, optimization

In my PHP scripts, I concatenate a lot HTML mixed with some PHP/MySQL data (the first example). Typically, my code looks like a mess because you can't bring any structure into this mix of code.

So, I was wondering, is the second script slower (or less performance) then the first script?

**First script**

```
$message = <div class="label" style="width:200px; float:left; text-align:right;">Organisation:</div>   
<div class="input" style="margin-left: 210px;"><b>' . $item1[0]['organisation'] . '</b>
</div><div class="label" style="width:200px; float:left; text-align:right;">Group:</div> <div class="input" style="margin-left: 210px;"><b>' .
  $item1[0]['group'] . '</b></div><div class="label" style="width:200px; float:left; 
text-align:right;">Name:</div> <div class="input" style="margin-left: 210px;"><b>' . $item1[0]['firstname'] . ' ' . $item[0]['lastname'] . '</b></div>
```

**Second script**

```
$message  = <div class="label" style="width:200px; float:left; text-align:right;">Organisation:</div>   
$message .= <div class="input" style="margin-left: 210px;"><b>' . $item1[0]['organisation'] . '</b></div>
$message .= <div class="label" style="width:200px; float:left; text-align:right;">Group:</div> 
$message .= <div class="input" style="margin-left: 210px;"><b>' .$item1[0]['group'] . '</b></div>
$message .= <div class="label" style="width:200px; float:left; text-align:right;">Name:</div> 
$message .= <div class="input" style="margin-left: 210px;"><b>' . $item1[0]['firstname'] . ' ' . $item[0]['lastname'] . '</b></div>
```

Or are there even better ways to handl PHP generated HTML pages?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Readability should always take priority over performance optimization. The fact that you're asking which one is faster is an indication that you have not actually traced any performance detriments back to the code in question. What you really seem to be asking is how to make the code more readable, which is understandable since code is meant to be read by humans and executed by computers.

My first advice in these situations is to always exit the PHP parser when you are outputting a large chunk of HTML and only tiny portions of PHP code.

```
<?php
/* Put your PHP code here */
$PHP = "PHP";
?>
<p>This is some html with a little <?php echo $PHP ?> code</p>
```

By closing your `PHP tags` to write large chunks of HTML code you simply tell PHP to stop parsing PHP code and output everything that follows as plain text up until another `opening PHP tag` is found.

Another option is to use [heredoc syntax](http://php.net/heredoc) which doesn't require all the messy single/double quote escaping.

Variable interpolation is possible directly inside string syntax so the following works:

```
$string = <<<EOL
<p>This is some html with a little $PHP code</p>
EOL;
```

Comment: So, in other words, the fact you concatenate this much code, doesn't influence the performance at all?

Comment: Obviously, everything you do in PHP has a performance impact, however dealing with strings is the least costly thing you can do in PHP. Whether you are concatenating strings or using string interpolation inside of string syntax, as demonstrated above, is pretty much the same amount of work for PHP. Because internally, PHP breaks up your string into parts when you put variables inside of the string.

Answer (score 2):

You won't notice any difference between the two. This is micro-optimization that 99.999% of sites will never need to worry about.

Personally I'd do something like this:

```
<div class="label" style="width:200px; float:left; text-align:right;">Organisation:</div>   
<div class="input" style="margin-left: 210px;"><b> <?php echp $item1[0]['organisation'] ?> </b></div>
<div class="label" style="width:200px; float:left; text-align:right;">Group:</div> 
<div class="input" style="margin-left: 210px;"><b><?php echo $item1[0]['group'] ?></b></div>
<div class="label" style="width:200px; float:left; text-align:right;">Name:</div>
```

Then, take it a step further and don't use inline styles. This will greatly improve readability and editability

Comment: So, its equally fast and performant? How about very large code snippets?

Comment: You need to organize the code better. Separate the HTML and PHP

Comment: "Early optimizations is the root of all evils"

Answer (score 0):

If you realy need the output to a string and want to write clean code I would use output buffering.

```
ob_start()
?>
<html>
<body>
  <div></div>
</body>
</html>
<?
$message = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
```

But it is even better to output actuall html and then only echo the PHP variables like `<?=$var?>` or event `<?php echo $var; ?>`

Comment: How is this going to help with his question?

Comment: He asked for a way to get html content to a string without being a mess. This is the way.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with relentless. You don't have a perfomance problem, but a maintenance problem ;-)

I'd suggest you take a look at this sample code, and see what you can make of it.

```
<form method="post" action="add_url_here">
    <label>
        Organisation:
    </label>
    <input type="text" name="organisation" value="<?php echo $item1[0]['organisation'] ?>" />

    <label>
        Group:
    </label>
    <input type="text" name="group"  value="<?php echo $item1[0]['group'] ?>" />

    <label>
        Name:
    </label>
    <input type="text" name="name"  value="<?php echo $item1[0]['name'] ?>" />
</form>
```

and for styling:

```
<style>
    label {
        width:200px; 
        float:left; 
        text-align:right;
    }

    input {
        margin-left: 210px;
    }

</style>
```

You could even do this:

```
$message =
  '<form method="post" action="add_url_here">
    <label>
    Organisation:
    </label>
    <input type="text" name="organisation" value="' . $item1[0]['organisation'] . '" />

    <label>
    Group:
    </label>
    <input type="text" name="group"  value="' . $item1[0]['group'] . '" />

    <label>
    Name:
    </label>
    <input type="text" name="name"  value="' . $item1[0]['name'] . '" />
</form>';
```

Comment: And how would you fit your PHP in this?